# Add sql table column before or after specific other column - by migrations in Laravel 4.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

Table 'users':

```
|id|name|address|post_code|deleted_at|created_at|
```

and I want add column 'phone_nr' somewhere between 'id' and 'deleted_at'

Is it possible by migrations in Laravel 4.1?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Yes.  Create a new migration using `php artisan migrate:make update_users_table`.

Then use the `table` command as follows (if you're using MySQL!):

```
Schema::table('users', function($table)
{
    $table->string('phone_nr')->after('id');
});
```

Once you've finished your migration, save it and run it using `php artisan migrate` and your table will be updated.

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations#column-modifiers

Comment: Note that you can change the 'after' value to the column of your choosing.

Comment: What about adding it to the front of the table so that it's the first column?

Comment: what if i need to add two columns back to back after specific column.
$table->integer('col1')->after('ref_col');
$table->integer('col2')->after('what');

Comment: You have to change the command to php artisan make:migration update_user_table

Comment: @rahulsingh probably not as much use to you nearly 2 years on, but see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/56645714/1372355 regarding your back-to-back new columns query.

Answer (score 19):

For anyone else wondering about @rahulsingh's query about adding multiple columns back to back after a single specific column:

```
$table->integer('col1')->after('ref_col');
$table->integer('col2')->after('what');
```

You can do this just by writing the new fields in reverse order, for example:

```
$table->integer('col4')->after('ref_col');
$table->integer('col3')->after('ref_col');
$table->integer('col2')->after('ref_col');
$table->integer('col1')->after('ref_col');
```

When you run this migration you'll find that your new fields `col`, `col2`, ... are in your intended order after the reference field `ref_col`.

Unfortunately there is no `before()` function for adding fields before an existing field. (If that existed we could keep the above statements in their real order.)

---

You **cannot** do chaining with fields that do not yet exist, for example:

```
$table->integer('col1')->after('ref_col');
$table->integer('col2')->after('col1');
$table->integer('col3')->after('col2');
$table->integer('col4')->after('col3');
```

This is because the migration blueprint is compiled to a single query thus executed as one, so when it comes to adding `col2` your database engine will complain that `col1` doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks for your reply but it worked for me simply like this  $table->integer('col1')->after('ref_col');
$table->integer('col2')->after('col1');

Comment: interesting, thanks for explaining why chaining isn't an option.

Answer (score 16):

The answer by James is still correct. However, Laravel 5 has slightly changed the make migration syntax:

```
php artisan make:migration add_google_auth_to_users_table --table=users
```

(I am aware this question is tagged Laravel 4, however it ranks quite high for the question ;) )

Comment: Had already figured out that the migration command was slightly different, but may come in helpful for others searching for a Laravel 5 solution. As you rightly mention, this ranks quite highly in generic Laravel searches.

Answer (score 12):

If you need add several columns after specific column in laravel 8:

> When using the MySQL database, the after method may be used to add
> columns after an existing column in the schema:

```
$table->after('password', function ($table) {
    $table->string('address_line1');
    $table->string('address_line2');
    $table->string('city');
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-order

Answer (score 1):

As of [Laravel 5.1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations), you can also position a new (mysql) column first. This was tested with Laravel 6:

```
Schema::table('foo', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->first();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

For latest versions of Laravel say 5-6

The command is

```
php artisan make:migration update_users_table
```

Then

```
php artisan migrate
```