# Laravel 5.1 Adding MySQL Column at the Front of a DB Table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I've noticed that there are other questions on Stack Exchange about how to add columns into a DB Table (for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982538/add-sql-table-column-before-or-after-specific-other-column-by-migrations-in-la)), but none of them address how to add a column into the table so that it is the FIRST column in the table.

I've seen that you can add ->after('column_name') to add the column after another column within the table, but is there a "->before('column_name')" that I could use (or some sort of smarter equivalent)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as luck would have it, I jumped the gun a bit with my question and managed to find my own answer.

In Laravel 5.1, you can use the column modifier ->first() in order to place the column first in the table.