# laravel 5.2 migration add column/field before or after specific column

Tags: php, laravel-5

i know how to add column/field to to database for example

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddStatusToPhoto extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('photos', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->integer('status');
        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }


}
```

but it will append to the last field of the table, but i want to add to specific column e.g insert the field after created_at, is it possible to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add sql table column before or after specific other column - by migrations in Laravel 4.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982538/add-sql-table-column-before-or-after-specific-other-column-by-migrations-in-la)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a `after` modifier you can use if you are on MySQL.

```
$table->integer('status')->after('created_at');
```

> `->after('column')`   Place the column "after" another column (MySQL Only)

[Laravel Docs - Migrations - Creating Columns - Column Modifiers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#creating-columns)

Comment: And there's a `->first()` to put it before everything else. There's no `->before()` though.