# how to add a new column between 2 columns in laravel

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, postman, database-migration

> migration file

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->longText('content');
            $table->string('short_description');
            $table->unsignedInteger('media_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('media_id')->references('id')->on('medias');
            $table->unsignedInteger('creator_id');
            $table->foreign('creator_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->boolean('hide')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

> after hide column i want to add 'privacy column'

Comment: you can add it into new migration file

Comment: Duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982538/add-sql-table-column-before-or-after-specific-other-column-by-migrations-in-la

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add sql table column before or after specific other column - by migrations in Laravel 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982538/add-sql-table-column-before-or-after-specific-other-column-by-migrations-in-la)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either add it to the migration file or create another migration like this :

```
 Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->string('privacy')->after('hide');
    });
```