# How to add multiple columns in already made table in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add multiple number of columns in the already made table in Laravel . How can i add multiple columns ?

I don't know how to do add columns in my table. I can only add single column one at a time.

Below given is my migration table up function.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('matches', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('sports');
        $table->string('match');
        $table->string('date');
        $table->string('time');
        $table->string('teamA');
        $table->longtext('teamA_flag');
        $table->string('teamB');
        $table->longtext('teamB_flag');
        $table->string('venue');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This is my table whose name is `matches`. I want to add two columns using Laravel. The name of columns are: `email` and `qualification`.

I am expecting to add multiple number of columns on the table (matches).
I want to add multiple number of columns in the already made table in Laravel . How can i add multiple columns ?

I don't know how to do add columns in my table. I can only add single column one at a time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create migration first by `php artisan make:migration alter_table_matches`,
open migration that is created by the command.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('matches', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('email')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->string('qualification')->nullable()->default(null);
    });
}
```

then in down function

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('matches', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('email');
        $table->dropColumn('qualification');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just run:

```
php artisan make:migration add_first_item_and_second_item_and_next_item_to_matches
```

This creates a migration file, you can then add:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('first_item');
        $table->string('second_item');
        $table->string('next_item');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('first_item');
        $table->dropColumn('second_item');
        $table->dropColumn('next_item');
    });
}
```

I hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 2):

You can add new columns by creating a new migration.
Remember to make the name of the migration as descriptive as possible.

> 2021_09_06_083822_update_email_column_and_add_agency_id_and_contact_source_id_in_contacts_table.php

```
class UpdateEmailColumnAndAddAgencyIdAndContactSourceIdInContactsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->integer('agency_id')->after('country_id')->references('agentid')->on('byt_agents');
            $table->foreignId('contact_source_id')->after('agency_id')->nullable()->constrained();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn(['agency_id', 'email']);
            $table->dropForeign(['contact_source_id']);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add `multiple columns` to an already existing `table` you can follow above [answer-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65332314/12719616)

but In that case, your all `columns` will be added at the end of already `existing columns`

so, In order to add `multiple columns` after a certain `column`. You can add `columns group` by using `callback/closure` as shown in the below snippet:

```
class AddFieldsInMatches extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('matches', function (Blueprint $table) {

            // closure to add multiple-columns after `id` column
            $table->after('id', function ($table) {
                $table->integer('email')->nullable();
                $table->integer('qualification')->nullable();
            });

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('matches', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('email');
            $table->dropColumn('qualification');
        });
    }
}
```

**Note:**

1. Make sure these `columns` must be `nullable` otherwise, you will get an error on running `php artisan migrate` command on the terminal
2. `callback/closure` approach is applicable after `Laravel 8.27` versions.

**Reference Article:** [click here](https://vumanhtrung.medium.com/add-multiple-columns-after-a-column-in-laravel-migrations-60bd0183870a)

**Other StackOverFlow threat:** [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67081051/12719616)

Comment: it doesn't necessarily need to be `nullable` if the column have a `default` value.

Comment: @Lenor yes you are right that's depends upon your requirement or usecase. but one thing must be added either `nullable()` or `default()` clause when you want to add more columns to the existing table.